# how to enable Instant Payment Notification Preferences of sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

in two years ago, i remember how to add how to add the notify url

1. Click Profile on the My Account tab.
2. Click Instant Payment Notification Preferences in the Selling Preferences column.
3. Click Choose IPN Settings to specify your listener’s URL and activate the listener.

but i want to test (don't use simulator) IPN, i can't find the selling preference column under the My account tab~

does it any changes between this two years?

thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification.
You can also set the IPN URL on a per-transaction basis, in which case you don't need to set it up in your profile, by setting `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://....">` in your PayPal Website Payments Standard button.

Comment: This is correct but PayPal has renamed the links slightly: Profile -> Selling Preferences -> Instant Payment Notification

Comment: This depends on the language of your account in fact; US and UK English differences. :)

Comment: Login to your account and try this URL https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify&fli=true

Comment: I could not find any links to this in profile, but @VineeshKalarickal solution worked.

Answer (score 8):

1. If you don't already have a developer account, go to https://developer.paypal.com/ to get a business account.
2. Sign in under the Business account (Find them under "Testing Tools"). Then open https://sandbox.paypal.com/ in a new browser and log in.
3. Profile Icon (Top Right) > Account Settings > Website payments > Instant payment notifications > Edit Settings

Comment: hi @Daniel i can't seem to login as business only. I have both a type personal and business. But here i dont see the link more>settings. I just see profile >settings and the choices Payment review and Negative testing. 

I tried to sign in under the Business account but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: There may have been changes to the site since posted this. I will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 6):

No this no longer exists, so i believe you have to use answer 1, and dynamically set the URL.  Paypal needs to update their website documentation better.

Comment: I agree. With the new interface, if click on Profile you'll be redirected to a login page!

Comment: You have to add the IPN address from the Paypal business account - so it's certainly not dynamic any more. Find the IPN setting buried away under Account >Profile >Notify Settings.

Comment: This isn't true. I was able to find the feature perfectly well as described by Daniel Dropik.

Answer (score 0):

Afirst set the notify_url variables in HTML.

```
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.example.com/ipn.php'>
```

After that enable PayPal IPN from your business account.

Step by step instructions has given here - [How to enable PayPal Instant Payment Notification](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-enable-paypal-ipn/)