# PayPal ipn notification request not sending

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a problem with Payal ipn notifications: There are 2 different forms, one is live and works for a long time, then the other one is only implemented.

This will work perfect in my sandbox, but when trying with live it with PayPal, it fails. No notification request is sent to my server. I've checked apache logs - nothing.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="business" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="name" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="AD::1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="myurl" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="notifyUrl" />
<div style="text-align: center">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="width: 147px" />
```

1. No firewall is installed
2. The script url is correct and works from outside
3. The script was developed on Zend Framework, so the URL is `[domain]/module/controller/action`  I have also tried with regular `[domain]/handler.php<br/>`
4. The IPN is On in the pp settings
5. The currently working script is on `[domain]`, the new script is on `[subdomain].[domain]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the 'IPN History' within your account?
Hover over 'History' and click 'IPN History' (or Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification > History).

This will give you the status of each IPN message we generated. These must be marked as 'Sent' in order for us (PayPal) to mark them as having been delivered.
If they are marked as 'Sent', this means we've delivered them to your IPN handler (the URL of which will be available too) and we have successfully receive a HTTP 200 'OK' response from your IPN handler.

If we do not receive a HTTP 200 for whichever reason (ssl handshake validation, network timeout, script error (500), server error (503), then we will reattempt delivery of the IPN message up to an additional fifteen times.

Comment: Hi Robert,
tnx for your answer. Main problem - account is not mine, but my client's, so debugging process is pain. I've just got ipn history screen, it sais all transactions has "disabled" status.

Comment: Okay, they'll need to enable IPN on their account in that case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913383/how-to-enable-instant-payment-notification-preferences-of-sandbox-account for details (same steps apply to live PayPal accounts too).

Comment: Yes. It help's at least :) It's bed to debug without ability to know what happening. Thank you.