# how to use paypal IPN and update a sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to update a my users information column once they have purchased this item on my website, but it just wont update! i know how to update queries and ive tried with $_SESSION's but nothing is working!

Answer (score 0):

You can Enable Paypal IPN from below URL

[how to enable Instant Payment Notification Preferences of sandbox account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913383/how-to-enable-instant-payment-notification-preferences-of-sandbox-account][1])

After enabling IPN in your paypal account you can get response from IPN at your return URL.

**Just pass notify URL from your paypal form like below**

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/test.php">
```

You will get the IPN response at test.php and then you can update the database accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How PayPal IPN Works :

1. User is Rediredcted From Merchant Website to Paypal.
2. User Pays the amount.
3. Paypal Call the Url with POST Parameters

So u need to Configure return url and in that u need to Update SQL.
For Testing u can use SANDBOX Account.

Google it. There are tons of Tutorials.